# Specify Data Folder location while installing MySQL on Windows

Tags: windows, mysql, installation

When installing MySQL 5.1 on a Windows machine, is it possible to specify where the Data Folder should go? The installer doesn't give an option for changing the Data Folder location, it defaults to "C:\Document and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\".

I'm installing MySQL 5.1.34 on Windows Server 2003.

**Follow-up**: I ended up manually editing `my.ini` and pointed `datadir` to the desired location. I just wish the installer had an option to change the location.

Comment: I added some notes re: transforming the setup MSI in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Have a look at this document:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-create-option-file.html

You can specify the data folder either in an option file, or on the command-line for the service.

Edit: I just pulled down the MSI and had a look, and I don't see any way to specify the data directory during install w/ an addt'l property on the command line.

You *can* transform the install with Orca, if you are familiar with Windows Installer, to change the "DataDir" location in the Directory table.

Comment: Can you give details of the command line ?

Comment: It's the "--datadir" option: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir

Answer (score 3):

When "Custom Installation" option is used (in version 5.7), or when adding features after the initial install, choosing the feature in the right pane will cause an "Advanced Option" link appears below the right pane.  This can be used to configure the install path for feature and data.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jcxe.png)